# unable to add attribute value on Error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, rails-i18n, model-validation

i have a custom validation method on user_calendar model:

```
class UserCalendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validate :should_match_company_calendars
  ...

  private
    def should_match_company_calendars
      day_company_calendars = (..query..)
      errors.add(:user, :company_calendar_match) if day_company_calendars.count < 1
    end
```

And this is the message on en.yml:

```
company_calendar_match: "%{value.full_name} does not work in the selected time lapse"
```

Validation works fine but the message shows '%{value.full_name}' instead of the actual value for full_name. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `I18n.t` method and pass value you want to show like below.

```
# model
errors.add(:user, I18n.t('... company_calendar_match', full_name: 'set value you want')) if day_company_calendars.count < 1

# en.yml
company_calendar_match: "%{full_name} does not work in the selected time lapse"
```

More detail is [Rails Guides - i18n api features](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-the-i18n-api-features)